# Algorithmia Model Persistence with Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, joblib

I'm pretty new to [Algorithmia](https://algorithmia.com/) but I've used scikit-learn a bit and I know how to persist my machine learning model after I've trained it with joblib:

```
from sklearn.externals joblib

model = RandomForestRegressor()
# Train the model, etc
joblib.dump(model, "prediction/model/model.pkl")
```

Now I want to host my ML model and call it as a service using Algorithmia, but I can't figure out how to read the model back. I've created a collection in Algorithmia called "testcollection" with a file called "model.pkl" that is the result of the joblib.dump call. According to the docs, this means my file should be located at

data://(username)/testcollection/model.pkl

I want to read in that model from the file using joblib.load. Here's my current algorithm in Algorithmia:

```
import Algorithmia

def apply(input):
    client = Algorithmia.client()
    f = client.file("data://(username)/testcollection/model.pkl")
    print(f.path)
    print(f.url)
    print(f.getName())
    model = joblib.load(f.url) # Or f.path, both don't work
    return "empty"
```

Here's the output:

```
(username)/testcollection/model.pkl
/v1/data/(username)/testcollection/model.pkl
model.pkl
```

And it errors at the joblib.load line, giving the "No such file or directory (whatever path I put in)"

Here's all the paths / urls I've tried in calling joblib.load:

- /v1/data/(username)/testcollection/model.pkl
- data://(username)/testcollection/model.pkl
- (username)/testcollection/model.pkl
- https://algorithmia.com/v1/data/(username)/testcollection/model.pkl

How do I load a model in from a file using joblib? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I think you just need to replace `f.url` with `f.name`
The path and url are supposed to be private fields inside the DataFile object... but it's python so nothing is private

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to access data on the DataAPI.

Here are 4 different methods to access files via the Python Client:

```
import Algorithmia

client = Algorithmia.client("<YOUR_API_KEY>")

dataFile = client.file("data://<USER_NAME>/<COLLECTION_NAME>/<FILE_NAME>").getFile()

dataText = client.file("data://<USER_NAME>/<COLLECTION_NAME>/<FILE_NAME>").getString()

dataJSON = client.file("data://<USER_NAME>/<COLLECTION_NAME>/<FILE_NAME>").getJson()

dataBytes = client.file("data://<USER_NAME>/<COLLECTION_NAME>/<FILE_NAME>").getBytes()
```

Since Sklearn expects the path to the model file, the easiest way to get that would be through a file object (aka. dataFile).

[According to the Official Python2.7 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.name), if a file object is created other than the `open()` function, the object attribute `name` usually corresponds to the path of the file.

In this case, you would need to write something like this:

```
import Algorithmia

def apply(input):

    # You don't need to write your API key if you're editing in the web editor
    client = Algorithmia.client()

    modelFile = client.file("data://(username)/testcollection/model.pkl").getFile()

    modelFilePath = modelFile.name

    model = joblib.load(modelFilePath)

    return "empty"
```

But [according to the Official Sklearn Model Persistence Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html), you should also be able to just pass file-like objects instead of file names.

Hence, we can just skip the part where we try to get the filename, and just pass the `modelFile` object:

```
import Algorithmia

def apply(input):

    # You don't need to write your API key if you're editing in the web editor
    client = Algorithmia.client()

    modelFile = client.file("data://(username)/testcollection/model.pkl").getFile()

    model = joblib.load(modelFile)

    return "empty"
```

Edit: [Here's also an article in the Offical Algorithmia Developer Center talking about Model Persistence in Scikit-Learn](http://developers.algorithmia.com/algorithm-development/model-guides/scikit/).

Full discloser: I work as an Algorithm Engineer at [Algorithmia](https://algorithmia.com/).